# How to call computeChargeTimeRemaining , Android BatteryManager?

Tags: android, batterymanager

What is the proper way to call computeChargeTimeRemaining ? The method doesn't exist when I try:

```
BatteryManager mBatteryManager = (BatteryManager)context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);

long time = mBatteryManager.computeChargeTimeRemaining();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The method doesn't exist when I try

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 28 (or higher, if you are reading this in the distant future).

Note that this method will only be available on Android 9.0+ devices. So, unless your `minSdkVersion` is 28 (or higher, for those of you reading this from your flying cars), you will need to take steps to only call this method on compatible devices:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
  long time = mBatteryManager.computeChargeTimeRemaining();
  // TODO something good with time
}
else {
  // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}
```

Comment: yes, I'm using the same functionality to get it, but it always returning -1 for me in Emulator and also in the Real device. But I can see the charge time remaining in my battery settings.